# Observable collection not reacting to it's collecion

Tags: c#, wpf

My ListBox doesn't react to my ObservableCollection.

This is the ListBox I am talking about.

```
<ListBox x:Name="CreateFieldsList"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="218"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="244"
         Margin="0,86,0,0"
         BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="4"
                  Width="215"
                  Height="32.96"
                  Background="White">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontWeight="Normal"
                           FontSize="18.667"
                           Padding="8,3,0,0" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In my MainWindow, I prepare the data binding like this

```
private ObservableCollection<FieldListItem> _fieldItems;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _fieldItems = new ObservableCollection<FieldListItem>();
    CreateFieldsList.ItemSource = _fieldItems;
}
```

A FieldListItem is following

```
public class FieldListItem : ViewItem
{
    private Field _field;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _field.Name; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _field.Value; }
    }

    public FieldListItem(Field f)
    {
        _field = f;           
    }
}
```

and finally the ViewItem

```
public class ViewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

    //The interface forces me to implement this. Why?
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }
}
```

I don't know why this isn't working. Could you please help?

Comment: You have not initialized `_fieldItems` before assigning the values to Itemsource.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentaly deleted that line. I did initialize the list. Still no solution.

Comment: But that list is empty. and also Specify what is not working? What is your expected behaviour or result and how is your program currently behaves.

Answer (score 0):

The INotifyPropertyChanged interface needs you to implement an event. Your event implementation does not work because registrations and deregistrations are ignored because the add and remove blocks are empty.

Implement the event without add and remove:

```
public class ViewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        var copy = PropertyChanged;
        if (copy != null) 
            copy(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do that, the `RaisePropertyChanged` Method says `PropertyChanged can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=` and `event property must have both add and remove accessors`